# Angular ng-repeat math

Tags: javascript, angularjs, math, angularjs-ng-repeat

i want to create some math inside an angular expression, its about the following; a user can have credit with the site or the user gets a percentage in discount. So i have the following code:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in NewArrivals">
<div>{{item.NewPrice - userCredit | number:2}}</div>
<div>
```

what I want to do is when a user is logged in that us userCredit becomes a number, that is simple, or if the user is not logged in that the userCredit is -5% of the item.NewPrice, and there is the problem.

This I have in the 'PageController.js'

```
    if (TheUser == "notThere") {
        console.log('5% discount for the user')
        var userDiscount = 0.95;
    } else {
        var userCredit = 300;
    }
```

How would i be able to get the newPrice minus 5% for each item in the ng-repeat if the user is logged in? Without making two different ng-repeats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can manage it

```
<div ng-repeat="item in NewArrivals">
  <div ng-if="userDiscount">{{item.NewPrice * userDiscount | number:2}}</div>
  <div ng-if="userCredit">{{item.NewPrice - userCredit | number:2}}</div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To make the value available on your template, you'll need to add it to the $scope (or if you were using controller-as syntax, you'd add it to the controller). Also, `var userCredit = 5%;` isn't valid javascript. So i would do it like this:

```
if (TheUser === "notThere") {
   $scope.userDiscount = 0.95;
} else {
   $scope.userDiscount = 1.0; // I'm not sure what value you want here.
}
```

And then on the template:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in NewArrivals">
  <div>{{item.NewPrice * userDiscount | number:2}}</div>
<div>
```

Comment: One is the actual amount (300) and the other is a percentage (5%) so i want to deduct or a percentage from the NewPrice or the actual credit amount the user has. In this case it deducts two times a percetage. I updated the question to make it perhaps more clear with your input

Comment: Perhaps you could give me an example of the expected results. Suppose there are two items, the first has price=10, the second has price=20. If `TheUser === "notThere"`, what should the page display? And if the `TheUser !== "notThere"`, what should the page display?

Comment: yes i just updated the question, one is a discount in percentage the other is a discount amount